# most effective query?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a function to get all keywords from a database

The database has two tables

> ```
> keywords             [id         | word      | account]   ( aliased as k )
> keywordsTemplateLink [templateId | keywordId]             ( aliased as ktl )
> ```

the functions signature is

`getKeywords($id = null){}`

so the way it works is,
if id != null a where clause is added which must limit the result set to keywords where `ktl.templateId = $id`

What would be the most effective way to achieve this query?

Im thinking `SELECT id, keyword FROM keywords k, templatekeywordlink tkl WHERE tkl.templateId= $id AND tkl.keywordId = k.id AND k.account=$account`

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getKeywords($id = null){
//query generated by function
$query .= ($id != null) ? ' where ktl.templateId = ' . $id : '';
}
```

Comment: Ternary is clever but `if` is more readable and is still one line in this case...    `if ($id != null) $query .= "..."`

Comment: Yeah that's true and your solution is even shorter!

Answer (score 1):

It is generally bad practice to create sql by variable concatenation in this way..

If you don't want some script kiddie to pwn you via sql injection, use [prepared queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

```
$stm = $dbo->prepare("SELECT id, keyword FROM keywords k, templatekeywordlink tkl WHERE tkl.templateId= ? AND k.account=?);

$stm->execute(array($id,$account));
```

Comment: im actually using code igniter, only reason I am writing it here like this is, people who help you dont need to know CI's functions, they can just write straight sql and ill translate it using the functions ;)